# List comprehensions in NumPy arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

In essence this is what I want to create

```
import numpy as np
N = 100  # POPULATION SIZE
D = 30  # DIMENSIONALITY
lowerB = [-5.12] * D  # LOWER BOUND (IN ALL DIMENSIONS)
upperB = [5.12] * D  # UPPER BOUND (IN ALL DIMENSIONS)
# INITIALISATION PHASE
X = np.empty([N, D])  # EMPTY FLIES ARRAY OF SIZE: (N,D)
# INITIALISE FLIES WITHIN BOUNDS
for i in range(N):
    for d in range(D):
        X[i, d] = np.random.uniform(lowerB[d], upperB[d])
```

but I want to do so without the for loops to save time and use List comprehensions
I have try things like

```
np.array([(x,y)for x in range(N)for y in range(D)])
```

but this doesn’t get me to an array like array([100,30]). Does anyone know a tutorial or the correct documentation I should be looking at so I can learn exactly how to do this?

Comment: If your bounds are the same for all dimensions, just use `X = np.random.uniform(lower, upper, size=(N, D))` with, in your case, `lower = -5.12` and `upper = 5.12`.

Comment: A 2D array in numpy is similar to a list of lists in Python. Your comprehension would've needed to be `[[inner_comprehension] for _ in range(...)]`, however, as @Engineero points out, none of this is necessary if what you're trying to do is instantiate a uniformly distributed random 2D array.

Comment: Read the help for `np.random.uniform`.  The bounds can be arrays.  There is also a size parameter.  Between those you should be able make the (N,D) shaped array with just one call.  No need for loops or list comprehensions.

Comment: How much time have you spent with https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html?